# How to exclude post and slider

Tags: wordpress

I want to load post 6th and later. and How to exclude slider in 2 pages

My Theme code `home.php`:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<ul class="content">

    <?php
    $counter = 0;
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
        $p = new Wpi_Article_Item(array(
            'show_snippet' => true,
            'show_category' => true,
            'show_comment_number' => true,
            'show_date' => true,
            'category' => 1,
            'snippet_length' => 200
        ));

        echo '<li class="item item-' . $counter . ' item-' . (($counter == 0) ? 'first active' : 'other') . ' item-' . (($counter % 2) ? 'odd' : 'even') . (($counter % 3) ? '' : ' item-triple') . '"><div class="inner">';

        echo $p->review() . $p->thumbnail('natural_full') . $p->cates() . $p->title() . $p->meta() . $p->snippet(true);

        echo '<div class="clear"></div></div></li>';
        $counter++;
    endwhile; /* end have_posts */

    ?>
```

Comment: Hello, Do you want to skip first 5 posts from the query ?

Comment: hi, yes . I want to skip first 5 posts from the query. 
and page 2 slider skip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use offset in your query.

```
    <ul>
    <?php
    global $post;
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => 10, 'offset'=> 6,  );
    $myposts = get_posts( $args );
    foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>
        <li>
            Your code here...
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </ul>
```

And try your code.

Comment: I'm sorry, i did not understand :( Your code here...?? Whatcode
For the code starting global $post; .... For home.php?

Comment: Can you just remove the counter of your query and put the offset. before while loop start. Or can you give me the home.php total code for the loop.

Comment: my home.php. Thank you
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6QDhyNOXnbNQ0hERTVmbjd2MHM

Comment: Yes, you can add <?php  $args = array( 'numberposts' => 10, 'offset'=> 6,  ); query_posts( $args ); ?> before the <?php if (have_posts()) : ?> line.  As you see i have used 'numberposts' => 10, you can add as per your requirements.

Comment: which page 2, You have to slide post in the home page right ?

Comment: Yes ok.
thank you sir. How to exclude the slider on the second page

Comment: yes www.xxxxxx.com slider ok but www.xxxxxxxx.com/page/2 slider no ?

Comment: can come to chart i will help you.

Comment: First of all thank you so much , slider problem seems solved but At the end of the page I have pagination ,  1 . 2 . 3  when I click to page 2 it doesn't work it is probably due to last added code , how can I fix it